# User Inputted Date Variable -1 to -5 Days in SOLARIS 10

Tags: bash, date, variables, solaris, solaris-10

I'm currently trying to put together a script that can take a user inputted date and generate the 5 previous days as variables whilst keeping the format YYYYMMDD.

The version I'm using is GNU bash, version 3.2.52(1)-release (i386-pc-solaris2.10) however it seems admin have blocked out usage of GNU Util so 'gdate' commands can't be used.

I have tried to use date -d which is invalid. Furthermore I have tried to use Perl but couldn't seem to grasp how to manipulate it to its best.

The script I currently have can be seen below but isn't returning the final date.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the date (format = YYYYMMDD) : " Udate
echo $Udate
U2date=`TZ=GMT+24${Udate}'+%Y%m%d'`
echo $U2date
```

My presumption is that if this code worked I would simply increase the +24 to +48 and so on for the further required dates.

Apologies if this is a simple issue to solve, I'm quite new to scripting and I'm learning on the go.

Comment: `date -d` is not supported or you are not sure how to use? What does invalid mean?

Answer (score 0):

echo "Enter the date (YYYYMMDD):"
read Udate
timestamp=`perl -MTime::Local=timelocal -e '@t = unpack ("A4A2A2", $ARGV[0]); $t[1]--; print timelocal(1,1,1,reverse
 @t);' $Udate`
U2date=`perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e 'print strftime("%Y%m%d", localtime($ARGV[0] -86400));' $timestamp`
U3date=`perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e 'print strftime("%Y%m%d", localtime($ARGV[0] -172800));' $timestamp`
U4date=`perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e 'print strftime("%Y%m%d", localtime($ARGV[0] -259200));' $timestamp`
U5date=`perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e 'print strftime("%Y%m%d", localtime($ARGV[0] -345600));' $timestamp`

For future reference in case anyone has a similar issue.